# Ubuntu 20.04 detects monitor but keeps it black screen

Tags: monitor

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and with Intel UHD Graphics 630, the second monitor is detected but it's all black, does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the resolution set to the correct (native) one?

Comment: Yes, everything correct, really, didn't understand what happened, something driver related low-level for sure, installed a gpu to solve the problem xD

Comment: Same here, with similar GPU: `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)`. The external monitor is detected as per the output shown by `xrandr` but the output is black. Did you solve it?